# Show equinumerosity between two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I struggle with one exercise and I'm not sure if my way of thinking is correct. We need to show, that intervals $(0,1)$ and $(0,1]$ are equinumerous - which should be correct, because both of them have continuum cardinality - so we should find a way to assign their subintervals together, right?

Of course there is main problem - we don't have bijection between open and closed interval. I have an idea to show it non-directly, by partitioning them for infinite parts - but I have a thought that it has very weak mathematical foundations.

Here is sketch of my proof: Divide intervals for infinite sum:
$$X=(0,\frac1n)+\{\frac1n\}+(\frac1n,\frac2n)+\{\frac2n\}+...+(\frac{n-1}n,1)+\{1\},$$
$$Y=(0,\frac1n)+\{\frac1n\}+(\frac1n,\frac2n)+\{\frac2n\}+...+(\frac{n-1}n,1),$$

where $n$ goes to infinity. Now we can assign subintervals of X and Y to each other and do the same with single elements - without worrying about elements without pair (because of infinity). Still, I have a thought that it is very weak thinking, near the "Leibniz mythology".

Comment: Is it ok to use the Schroeder Bernstein theorem?

Answer (score 3):

take the identity map on the irrationals.

For the rationals, you have to define a map from the rationals with one extra element to the rationals.

The rationals are bijective with the naturals so just slide them along by 1.