# What is the cardinality of $\mathbb N \times \mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, cardinals

I was wondering what is the cardinality of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{R}$. My guess is that  it is the same as $\# \mathbb{R}=c$ but I haven't been able to prove it.

I was thinking that one can easily find a surjective function $f: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. For example taking $f(x, y) = y$. This would prove that $\# \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{R} \geq \# \mathbb{R}$. But is there a bijective function between the two sets?

Comment: Yes.  It's not hard to construct a bijection $f: [0, 1) \to \Bbb R$.  (Note that this bijection won't be continuous.)  And of course, it's easy to construct a bijection $g: \Bbb Z \to  \Bbb N$.  Once you have those, it's not hard to create the bijection you need.

Comment: @Rober Shore I don't understand how are those bijections related to the bijection $h:\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @peterfizza Define $h(n, x)=n+f(x)$.

Comment: @Robert Shore I don't see why $h$ is surjective and where does $g$ come into play?

Comment: @peterfizza Compose $g$ with $h$.

Comment: @Robert Shore $g$ can't be composed with $h$, since we have $h: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and $g: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. I don't see what you mean.$

Comment: @Anne Bauval it would if it showed there is a bijection $\mathbb{Z} \times [0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Then it does answer the question @Anne Bauval. I guess it should be put into an answer in order to mark the question as solved.

Comment: @ peterfizza: answering to duplicates is tirelessly blamed by moderators like @BillDubuque ,with a link to https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards

Comment: @Anne Bauval: it seems a shame to close this question - it asks for a bijection to make explicit the equal cardinality, not just a proof that the two sets have the same cardinality, which is what the reference provides.

Comment: @mcd The duplicate not only suggest an "easy to see" bijection $\Bbb Z\times[0,1)$ but also an obvious one $\Bbb N\to\Bbb Z$, and a (less obvious but "not hard", said Robert in the 1st comment above) [bijection $[0,1)\to\Bbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1660726/386889), and I find such a toolbox more instructive than a ready-made answer. And after all, closing is not that bad since you already gave an answer here. But if you would like other people to also answer (at their own risks ;-) ), you can vote for reopening.

Answer (score 0):

If $f: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is a bijection, you could use $(n, x) \mapsto f(n, \lfloor x \rfloor)  + \{x\}$ to get the bijection you want.

For $f$, you could have $f(n,0) =-n$, $f(n, z)= (z+n)^2+(z-n)$ for $z>0$ and $f(n, z)= (n-z)^2-(z+n)-1$ for $z<0$.